# How do you create a dynamic where clause for a custom SQL query in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

We need to do a count with a double group by, which to my knowledge is not supported by ActiveRecord in Rails 2.3, so we're doing a custom SQL query, something like:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select COUNT(*), author_id, call_type_id from signup_calls group by author_id, call_type_id")
```

However, we also need to filter the signup calls being counted by three user selected filters,   which need to be included in the where clause.

Is there someway I can use the ActiveRecord helpers to help generate the where clause.  If not, what's the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
SignupCall.select('count(*) as signup_count, author_id, call_type_id').group('author_id, call_type_id')
```

Then just chain where clauses afterwards.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that we're using Rails 2.3, which doesn't have select or group.